# Design and position lens and sensor for light simulator raytracer

Tags: camera, render, simulation, raytracing, light

I am creating a light simulator in C++ for a 3D-scene (for now a "Cornell box"). This is a project for a graphics course I'm doing, and I do not seek to make it fast, just to render one decent image is fine by me, even if it takes hours. I want to demonstrate global illumination and DOF.

Instead of a regular raytracer, the rays are emitted from a point light source, bounces on geometry in the scene and eventually hits the light sensor, which is a rectangle in the 3D-environment, and depending on where the ray hits the sensor, the intensity is increased for that pixel on the screen.

Between the sensor and the scene, there is a lens which I seek to design and position properly in order to simulate a camera. The lens is also a flat surface but the normals (for when the ray hits the lens and gets refracted) are computed according to a thin, spherical lens.

My current setup, which is derived from formulas for lenses and such I found on Wikipedia:

```
The Cornell box: x, y and z in between -1 and 1
Sensor dimensions: 0.2 x 0.2 (too large?)
Sensor position: 0, 0, -2.9
Sensor resolution: ~ 150 x 150 px
Lens dimensions: 0.4 x 0.4 (rectangular shape for now, spherical normals)
Lens position: sensor position + (0, 0, 0.1037) (in front of sensor)
Lens IOR: 1.52 (glass)
Lens focal length: 0.1
Lens radius: 0.104
```

[image: Current rendering]

What is seen is mainly the point light source, unfocused.

Ideally I want around half of the box (z between -.5 and .5) to be focused, so that the DOF can be visible. **My question is: how can I calibrate the sensor and lens to make an image appear?** I don't think I can make the lens and sensor too small, then almost all the rays will be discarded because they won't hit the camera, and thus make the rendering computationally unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is: where to put the camera? If you know the focal length of your lens (that is, the distance behind the lens where it will focus parallel incoming rays), then it's straightforward to know the field of view and place the camera so that the scene is correctly framed. Is that what you're asking?

If so, calculate that intersection distance and the rest will fall into place.

Comment: The sensor is in the same location as the pinhole-camera used to be when I used a regular raytracer for rendering, the rendered image confirms that the placement of the camera is at least OK. I suspect the lens and/or sensor might be too large, resulting in a depth of field that is so narrow that almost the entire scene gets blurred. The light source shouldn't look so large since it's an omnidirectional point light.

Comment: If you have used a true pinhole model (that is, rays trace through a pinhole and the image is rendered UPDIDE DOWN), then the lens curvature (or index of refraction) should be tuned so that its focal length is the same as the distance from the pinhole to the image plane. Then place the lens where the pinhole once was.

To focus, either move the lens toward the subject or just reduce the size of the lens (in effect, raising the virtual f/stop). A few minutes with a magnifying glass and a ruler, or any manual-focusing camera like an SLR or rangefinder, may be instructive here.